# How to specify special encoding for german characters in pd.read_sql

Tags: jupyter-notebook, oracle-sqldeveloper

After some issues trying to connect to the database via Jupyter, it works now.

However, when trying to contact the database, there are some issues with 2 tables (the others works well).

FYI:

I'm working with datas from Germany, so maybe the problem is with the special characters ü,ä,ö?

I,ve been thinking to specify to the connection line that it is special encoding but I have no ideas how to do it.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

# The connection
conn = cx_Oracle.Connection(user='', password='', dsn='')

# The Query
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
'''select * from CB_CONTRACTS''', conn)

# Define the DF
df_CRH = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query)

# Display the DF
df_CRH.head()
```

The output should be a data frame containing all the query.
As I said, it works for 8/10 tables except those 2 that I've been struggling with.

The Error Message:
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 23: character maps to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `cx_Oracle.connection()` accepts `encoding` and `nencoding` parameters, see [`cx_Oracle.connect()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect).  Alternatively you can set the NLS_LANG environment variable before starting python. Update: cx_Oracle version 8 uses the UTF-8 character set by default, and will ignore the character set component of NLS_LANG: see [Character sets and globalization](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html).
- `cursor.var()` has an `encodingErrors` parameter, see [`Cursor.var`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.var) and https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/162

Comment: Thanks for your response!                                                                                                    The problem wasn't about the encoding. The problem was due to my configuration: I had python 64bit with Oracle 32bit. Furthermore, I also didn't have the instant client (11g). So, after downloading those right versions, I did the same thing and it worked.

Comment: Yes, those would be problems.